# NullPointerException when creating object

Tags: java, android

I have this class with its constructor as defined below.
The issue is when I try to create an object of it I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
public class someClass extends Activity {
    public static String sharedPreferencesFileName = "myShared";
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    public someClass() {
        this.sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesFileName,0);
    }
```

I am calling this from another class

```
someClass someObj = new someClass();
```

Comment: I see your class extends `Activity`. It has its own lifecycle. Don't use the default constructor (or any constructor) to initialize your variables. Do it on the `onCreate` method.

Comment: why does your object extend activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your constructor and use the `onCreate()` as constructor's are not typical usage when doing android activities.

```
public class someClass extends Activity {
    public static String sharedPreferencesFileName = "myShared";
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesFileName,0);
    }
```

Comment: will `onCreate()` be called when i create the object of this class?

Comment: @Maven you should not be creating an object of an activity at all, an activity gets created when you start it with an intent

Comment: @Maven,  It will be called when the `someClass` activity starts up thru your startActivity(intent) usage.

Comment: actually this class is not an activity. If I don’t extend it from activity I get `unable to resolve getSharedPreferences` error. This is the only reason I have extending it from there.

Comment: whats `public class someClass extends Activity` all about then?

Answer (score 1):

Is `someClass` is normal java class?

Then no need to extends Activity, Use class constructor for getting Context in `someClass` form Activity to access `getSharedPreferences` as:

```
public someClass(Context mContext){
        this.sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(s
                     haredPreferencesFileName,0);

}
```

Comment: If I don’t extend it from activity I get `unable to resolve getSharedPreferences` error. This is the only reason I have extending it from there.